# MongoDB aggregation graphlookup child's parent

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got some documents representing folders. I'd like to match every folder's parent if it has one.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2"},"name":"A"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f3"},"parentFolderId":"5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2","name":"B"}
```

Even if the parent-child relationships are deeper, for **A** I need an **empty parent folder**, and for **B** **parent folder A**. I tried to use GraphLookup for this but it's not working (every `parentFolder` is empty), and I don't know what I'm missing:

```
db.folders.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            convertedId: { $toString: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "folders",
            startWith: "$parentFolderId",
            connectFromField: "parentFolderId",
            connectToField: "convertedId",
            as: "parentFolder",
            maxDepth: 0,
        }
    }
])
```

If I flip the `startWith`, `connectFromField`, `connectToFields` respectively, I get the *reverse* of what I need, A has an array which is containing B, B has nothing.

Edit:

With the non-working lookup, I get the following result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2"), "name" : "A", "convertedId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2", "parentFolder" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f3"), "parentFolderId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2", "name" : "B", "convertedId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f3", "parentFolder" : [ ] }
```

What I'd need is something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2"), "name" : "A", "convertedId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2", "parentFolder" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f3"), "parentFolderId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2", "name" : "B", "convertedId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f3", "parentFolder" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2"), "name" : "A", "convertedId" : "5f8c406fc8c88110e0d927f2" } ] }
```

The only difference I see from the official "reportsTo" example that I'm using the ID field to match the documents, but that shouldn't be a problem, since I'm not using the ObjectID: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Comment: can you post what you are getting currently and what is your expected result?

Comment: @wak786 I've updated the question with the results. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem resides in `convertedId`, since it's populated dynamically and before `$graphLookup` is done (it doesn't count with). Try: store `parentFolderId` as `ObjectId` and `connectToField` with `_id` field.

Comment: @Valijon Thank you, I will try that. However, if it's not considering the convertedId, how it "works" when I switch parentFolderId and convertedId in the lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this is what you are looking for. I did not require additional `convertedId` field. So i have not added that. If you want I can add that too. But i think that would be redundant information.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: {
        $toObjectId: "$parentFolderId"
      },
      connectFromField: "parentFolderId",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "parentFolder",
      maxDepth: 0,
      
    }
  }
])
```

Link to [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-5xYrTAfTaJ)